How to implement In-App-Update in React Native Android using Kotlin?
I am going through https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/kotlin-java#kotlin this link but this gives me many import errors and I am unable to understand the documentation and also the errors that code giving me?
this is my MainApplication.kt Code 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bgQUzNhgukhmmKKacr7pkZcC1V1HbqFnMTSiMDuQBug/edit?usp=sharing
Can somebody help me with this.. please..
And please guide me for IOS device In-App-Update if IOS allows it.
I was tried so many importing suggestion giving by android studio but none of them worked

you could take a look at the native code made by this package, I believe they already have the in-app-update
https://github.com/SudoPlz/sp-react-native-in-app-updates/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/sudoplz/rninappupdates/SpReactNativeInAppUpdatesModule.java

and here another package you can check the code also
https://github.com/kumparan/react-native-android-inapp-updates/tree/master
